# How does kubelet interpret the results of healthcheck end point?

Tags: linux, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod, kubelet

Below is the Pod resource type for deploying a container:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-container
  labels:
    app: myapp
    rel: stable
spec:
  containers:
  - name: my-container
    image: myimage:latest
    resources:
      limits:
        memory: "128Mi" #128 MB
        cpu: "200m" #200 millicpu (.2 cpu or 20% of the cpu)
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    livenessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /health-check
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 15
      timeoutSeconds: 2 # Default is 1
      periodSeconds: 5 # Default is 10
      failureThreshold: 1 # Default is 3
    readinessProbe:
      httpGet:
        path: /health-check
        port: 80
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 5 # Default is 10
      failureThreshold: 1 # Default is 3
```

---

the `/health-check` end point returns http status `200` status with below json:

```
{
    "details": {
        "app": {
            "framework": "gin",
            "name": "my-app-local",
            "version": "v1"
        },
        "databases": [
            {
                "database": "my_db",
                "host": "localhost",
                "name": "mysql",
                "status": "Normal"
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": "Normal"
}
```

---

Given above Pod yaml, how does kubelet read the `status` value for `"databases"` & `"app"`? as part of `livenessProbe` or `readinessProbe`, to ensure container is running fine.

Answer (score 1):

It does not work like that, it checks the return code of http requests. Here is snippet from the documentation(port 80 in this case):

> To perform a probe, the kubelet sends an HTTP GET request to the
> server that is running in the container and listening on port 8080.
>
> If the handler for the server's /healthz path returns a success code,
> the kubelet considers the container to be alive and healthy. If the
> handler returns a failure code, the kubelet kills the container and
> restarts it.  Any code greater than or equal to 200 and less than 400
> indicates success. Any other code indicates failure

If you really need to read `json` response,then do `curl` and use `jq` or `grep` to find the status in `json` response. For `jq` something like `jq '.details.databases[].status'`

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - sh
    - -c
    - curl --silent http://localhost:80/healthz | grep .......
```