# Get the readiness probe logs

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks

Good afternoon, I have a cluster in AKS with a microservice that has a readiness which queries 3 services on which it depends to function.

```
    readinessProbe:
      failureThreshold: 3
      httpGet:
        path: / readiness
        port: http
        scheme: HTTP
      initialDelaySeconds: 3
      periodSeconds: 3
      successThreshold: 1
      timeoutSeconds: 1
```

{"podname": "podname", "healths": [{"name": "redis", "status": "ok"}, {"name": "pushPublisher", "status": "ok"}, {"name": "postgres", "status": "ok"}]}

Sometimes the microservice is put off (running 0/1) due to the failure of some of the services in the readiness probe and in the events it is not found which service is the one that falls or exceeds the timeout time. Setting a higher value for timeoutSeconds would not be a solution because we do not know what the origin of the problem is.

Is there a way to view the readiness probe logs or redirect the logs to see them somewhere beyond the event information? in events I only have the following:
http-get http: //: http / readiness delay = 3s timeout = 1s period = 3s # success = 1 # failure = 3

Comment: if you could  use `command` in the probe try running `curl --silent http://localhost:<your app port>/path-of-endpoint --trace-ascii /dev/stdout` , this would print the error in the `kubectl describe pod` command.  example at https://stackoverflow.com/a/68520244/6309601